# GitLab unicorn doesn't listen on 8080

Tags: gitlab

I run latest GitLab-CE (`gitlab-ce-12.0.3-ce.0.el7.x86_64`) on CentOS 7. It is omnibus install and it ran well until yesterday. After update of some OS packages* and system restart, GitLab doesn't work.

* List of updated packages:

- 7:device-mapper-1.02.149-10.el7_6.8.x86_64
- 7:device-mapper-event-1.02.149-10.el7_6.8.x86_64
- 7:device-mapper-event-libs-1.02.149-10.el7_6.8.x86_64
- 7:device-mapper-libs-1.02.149-10.el7_6.8.x86_64
- 7:lvm2-2.02.180-10.el7_6.8.x86_64
- 7:lvm2-libs-2.02.180-10.el7_6.8.x86_64
- gitlab-runner-12.0.2-1.x86_64
- glibc-2.17-260.el7_6.6.x86_64
- glibc-common-2.17-260.el7_6.6.x86_64
- glibc-devel-2.17-260.el7_6.6.x86_64
- glibc-headers-2.17-260.el7_6.6.x86_64
- libteam-1.27-6.el7_6.1.x86_64
- systemd-219-62.el7_6.7.x86_64
- systemd-libs-219-62.el7_6.7.x86_64
- systemd-sysv-219-62.el7_6.7.x86_64
- teamd-1.27-6.el7_6.1.x86_64
- tzdata-2019b-1.el7.noarch

Symptoms:

502 Whoops, GitLab is taking too much time to respond. (when accessing web interface)

GitLab: Failed to authorize your Git request: internal API unreachable (when trying git pull)

`gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and `gitlab-ctl restart` did not help.

In `/var/log/gitlab/unicorn/unicorn_stderr.log` I found:

```
I, [2019-07-17T10:23:20.831800 #23128]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2019-07-17T10:24:04.558224 #23128]  INFO -- : listening on addr=127.0.0.1:8080 fd=19
I, [2019-07-17T10:24:04.558414 #23128]  INFO -- : unlinking existing socket=/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket
I, [2019-07-17T10:24:04.558640 #23128]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket fd=20
E, [2019-07-17T10:24:04.559419 #23128] ERROR -- : Operation not permitted (Errno::EPERM)
/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/unicorn.rb:47:in `kill'
/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/unicorn.rb:47:in `block in reload'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:543:in `spawn_missing_workers'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:142:in `start'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn:23:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:463:in `exec'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

What is wrong with my unicorn and how to repair it?

I found that rubby is runnig as `git` user:

```
$ sudo ps -ef | grep ruby
git      22951 22928  0 10:23 ?        00:00:06 ruby /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitaly-ruby/bin/gitaly-ruby 22928 /tmp/gitaly-ruby531460471/socket.0
git      22952 22928  0 10:23 ?        00:00:06 ruby /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitaly-ruby/bin/gitaly-ruby 22928 /tmp/gitaly-ruby531460471/socket.1
```

and sockets are owned by `git` user too:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/gitaly-ruby531460471/socket.{0,1} /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket
srwxr-xr-x. 1 git git 0 Jul 17 10:23 /tmp/gitaly-ruby531460471/socket.0
srwxr-xr-x. 1 git git 0 Jul 17 10:23 /tmp/gitaly-ruby531460471/socket.1
srwxrwxrwx. 1 git git 0 Jul 17 11:32 /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket
```

Port 8080 is not in use:

```
$ sudo ss -t -u -n | grep -e Netid -e 8080
Netid  State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried *a lot* ways to repair Gitlab, I compared it with new, fresh install on virtual machine, deleted caches, reinstalled code (`yum reinstall gitlab-ce`) ... without success.

Finally, I decided to uninstall Gitlab, then I removed most of files, including repositories (I retained `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`, secrets and accounts), made new install and restored data from backup.

Gitlab is working again now.

This question is no longer relevant.